# How to define a scope from another one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new in Angular/Asp.net/Javascript. With that said:

I have this code to get every record from a SQL Server table:

```
   public JsonResult GetClientes()
    {
        var db = new RexsoftEntities();
        var Clientes = db.CLIENTES.ToList();
        return Json(Clientes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And in JS:

```
    myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $http.get('/app/GetClientes')

    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.clientes = result;

    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });


    });
```

In the table CLIENTES I have two columns for now: ID and NAME.

Now that I have all the records in the $scope.Clientes, I want to create another one but with just the ID value of the first record of the same $scope().

Let's say I have:

|  ID  | NAME  |

|  02  |  Alex |

|  01  |  Phil |

How can I get the value "01"?

I really don't want to create another JsonResult just to do that - I'm avoiding connecting to the databazse again.

Comment: `$scope.firstId = $scope.clientes[0].id`?

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to do? Note that if you have a large user base you would want an endpoint that only returned one user also probably...and most definitely if you only want to get current user

Comment: @tcooc It worked but is there a way to do it in a descendant way? I realised that i need the last record not the first.

Comment: @charlietfl There is three views in the project. One of them is to search clients - that's why I put every records in the $scope.clientes. The other is to  register clients - after recording I update the $scope.clientes and call for the third view that records their pets (animals). In this last view I need the last added clients id - the resolution that I found was to insert this value in a scope to use it later to record the pets into the database.

Comment: @tcooc Found it, man. Thx. $scope.clientes[$scope.clientes.length - 1].Id;